# loop through list in jquery from certain index to another index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

guys this my first time in JQuery... i am trying to loop through list in jquery sent from servlet to jsp from certain index to another certain index but i failed to do that  .. here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% List lst = (List) session.getAttribute("MyList");%>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        lst.each(function() {
            alert(this);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you are mixing java and javascript

Comment: please keep in mind i am beginner :)

Comment: you don't need js here just use a for loop or use jstl to loop over `lst`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular Javascript `for` loop.

First of all understand how a jQuery DOM selection is made up.

If you set a variable equal to `$("body")`, the variable can be named `$myJquerySelection`. It is still a local variable even though it has a dollar sign. The dollar sign variable name is a convention that shows the variable equals a jQuery selection.

The jQuery selection actually refers to an array of DOM nodes. Note that all jQuery selections are arrays, even if they only contain a single element like `$("body")`.

So you can say `var firstDOMnode = $myJquerySelection[0]`. This `firstDOMnode` variable is a DOM node, not a jQuery selection, so jQuery methods can't be called on it. To make it a jQuery selection, just wrap it in `$()`.

See the following example:

```
var $jQuerySelection = $("a");
var firstDOMnode = $jQuerySelection[0];
var $firstDOMnode = $(firstDOMnode)
```

This same approach can be used when iterating:

```
var $manyDOMnodes = $("*");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var currentDOMnode = $manyDOMnodes[i];
  var $currentDOMnode = $(currentDOMnode);
  $currentDOMnode.append("using a jquery method here")
}
```

The start and end indexes for iteration can be changed in the `for` loop.

This example goes from 0 to 5 and increases by 1 each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$.each` to loop over element list.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/sns8xwk6/).

```js
function createList() {
  var html = "<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html += "<li class='list'>" + i + "</li>"
  }
  html += "</ul>";
  $("#content").append(html);
}

createList();

$(".btn").on("click", function updateElements() {
  $.each($(".list"), function(index, el) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      $(el).toggleClass("selected");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.list {
  color: blue;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button class="btn">Updated Elements</button>
```